# Unknown service error botocore

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, botocore

I'm trying to use the recent Amazon transcribe service with:

```
transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe')
```

and I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'transcribe'. Valid service names are: ...
```

I've tried upgrading boto3 and botocore using:

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that is causing this error?

Comment: Command `pip install botocore --upgrade` worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature has not landed in `botocore` yet.  It's unfortunate that [usage examples](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-transcribe-scalable-and-accurate-automatic-speech-recognition/) appeared in the AWS docs already, when those service definitions are not released to PyPI yet.

Watch [PR 1356](https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1356) for merging.