# Boto3 does not support transcribe service

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, transcription

I'm using [Boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package in order to transcribe audio files using [aws transcribe service](https://console.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/)

I'm following [AWS official example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/getting-started-python.html) but getting this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'transcribe'
```

I'm using latest boto3 package and aws cli.
Just to be clear - im able to use their [web interface](https://console.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/home#createJob) to transcribe

Comment: This feature is not yet supported. Refer this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307919/unknown-service-error-botocore